# Neovim - gitgutter diff column appears in Nerd Tree

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree, neovim

So gitgutter diff column appear in my NERDTree buffer whether I have option:

```
let g:gitgutter_sign_column_always = 1
```

enabled or disabled.

Sometimes it doesn't appear at start but after I switch between tree and file buffer few times, it appears.

Here is how it looks like:
[image: vim-screen]

My .vimrc can be found [here](https://github.com/dominikduda/config_files/blob/master/.vimrc).

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: I can't confirm this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exacly causes this issue but i worked it around using:

```
let g:gitgutter_eager = 0
```

which disables signs updates when buffer/tab is switched.